# apt spewing warnings after libreoffice update

Tags: 14.04, apt, libreoffice

I run a 14.04 system and pick up libreoffice from the official ppa (http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu trusty main).

This morning the ppa provided a bunch of updates. While incorporating them, I got multiple warnings of the form

```
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
```

and the advice to

```
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

(which did not help when run)

Oddly, I do not seem to have the package `libreoffice-l10n` installed.

These warnings do not seem to have much effect, in that the updates succeeded.

Now, however, they show up on every subsequent `sudo apt update` or similar command.

How can I rid my system of these warnings?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't help ?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The warnings are issued at the `sudo apt-get update` step, and `upgrade` reports no packages to install or upgrade.

Comment: Hello! I would like to hook up to this thread as I had the same problem just some minutes ago. I wanted to add the wine repository and ended up with about a hundred warning lines for "libreoffice-l10n". I tried "sudo apt-get update", "… dist-upgrade", "… upgrade", "… install -f", "… autoremove" and none of it helped.

Comment: I have found that if I disable the libreoffice ppa and run `sudo apt-get update` I do not get the warnings.  Of course this moves all the libreoffice packages to local.

Comment: Those warnings are probably due to a minor bug in the package, which will hopefully be fixed in a future version. Meanwhile, they can safely be ignored, especially if the package is not installed.

Comment: I can confirm that these warnings are harmless. In the meantime I installed wine and other things and ran some updates too and all went fine. But anyhow, it would be much nicer with a proper LO5.3 ppa. Hopefully this will be fixed in a few days.

Comment: I got rid of these errors by going into software sources, PPAs, then removing the PPAs that I had just added and seemed to cause it (ricotz/docky), upgrade and update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was apparently fixed today, 3rd April 2017. From an older comment of mine:

> Those warnings are probably due to a minor bug in the package, which will hopefully be fixed in a future version. Meanwhile, they can safely be ignored, especially if the package is not installed.

Comment: Thanks from me too. All bugs are gone – unfortunately except one: "libreoffice-l10n-de" is still not updating.

Comment: @Jens Yes the l10n packages seem to have another bug where they don't "see" that the main libreoffice paxkages are installed, and so they can't be installed because of "missing dependencies"...

Comment: @fkraiem: Thanks for the info. That surely means probably another two months of waiting for a solution. Well, it could be worse. LO is running – _if I don't use hyphenation_ – and I'm fine with that for so far :)

Comment: This last issue has been **solved** today with an update for "libreoffice-help-de", "libreoffice-help-en-us" & "libreoffice-l10n-de". Everything is working fine now and even a hanging of the muon updater – _obvioulsy caused by this libreoffice update problem_ – has also been solved too. **To whom so ever: THANK YOU VERY MUCH :))**

Answer (score 3):

Libreoffice 5.3 was released (today) and does not support all languages yet. For example German is not supported*. I think this might cause the problem.
Sadly, the human theme was also removed (why?), so I decided to

- switch back to Libreoffice 5.2
- Remove ppa:libreoffice/ppa
- and choose the one for 5.2:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-2
  ```

  sudo apt-get update

If you made the same mistake as I did, and already upgraded to 5.3, you have to run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

and reinstall LibreOffice.
The problem lines no longer appear.

*https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/5.3/de#Lokalisierung

Comment: Thank  you for the response. My goal is to retain 5.3 and get rid of the warnings.

Answer (score 2):

I want to provide a little more detail and amplify Ophilon's answer.

1. Remove the current ppa for LibreOffice

   `sudo apt-get-repository --remove  ppa:libreoffice/ppa`
2. Add the older respoistory (5.2)

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-2`
3. Purge LibreOffice

   `sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core libreoffice-common
    sudo apt-get autoremove --purge`
4. Run `sudo apt-get update`
5. When I tried to install 5.2 using `apt`, however, I got broken dependencies.
   So I suggest downloading this package:

http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/5.2.5.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.2.5.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

or 
http://downloadarchive.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/old/5.2.5.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.2.5.1_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz for 32-bit systems

6. Extract the archive and change to the `/DEBS` directory (that's the full path).

   6a. If you have been using Nautilus up to now, right-click and select "Open in Terminal".
7. Now install

   `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Comment: Thank  you for the response. My goal is to retain 5.3 and get rid of the warnings.

Comment: I have been informed by one user (Geno) that the broken package error in step 5 was fixable (at least on that user's own system) by purging ure, uno-libs3, hyphen-* and libreoffice-style-human before the installation. But the user doesn't exactly know which of those was the root cause (nor do I).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my solution that worked on my system:

1. Temporarily comment with # the lines in the libreoffice.list so that the update process does not use it
2. `sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean`
3. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean`
4. Uncomment the lines in the libreoffice.list
5. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean`

In my case it updated without problems after I took those steps.

Comment: Sorry, but that did not fix the problem for me.  I still get the warnings when I execute step 5 of your procedure.

Comment: I find no file libreoffice.list on my computer. Which file exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the package manager built into elementary OS, and received the same error messages (double checked through apt-get) `Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n`.

What I did to resolve this was to disable the download of the libreoffice foreign language packages (other than English).  By default, the foreign language packages themselves were disabled, but their associated help files were not e.g. these packages.

[image: Screenshot]

Disabling both the language files and the help files in my package manager "details of updates" list resulted in a clean update and no error messages.

Comment: For me, it was fixed by an update pushed out on 4/3/2017.  See accepted answer.

Comment: Was this a general update or a specific package? The accepted answer doesn't elaborate.  I've been trying to update a few times over the last week and only disabling the help files worked.