# Ubuntu 14.04: Error with "apt-get update": W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa

I'm getting this error every time I do `apt-get update`

```
Ign http://ni.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://ni.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://ni.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
...
...
...
...
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

This error started to show after I upgraded LibreOffice form 5.2 to 5.3 with the LibreOffice PPA: `ppa:libreoffice/ppa`.

The thing is that everything is working fine. I can update/upgrade the system, I can install packages, delete packages, etc. The problem is just with the error.

I tried: `apt-get autoclean`, `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get install -f`, and a lot of other things and nothing removes that ugly error.

Comment: Have you tried purging your existing libreoffice and completely reinstalling?

Comment: I just tried that. Removed all installed packages from the PPA. Removed the PPA with "ppa-purge". The error disappears. But after adding the PPA again the error shows up. So it seems the problem is with the PPA.

Comment: Follow the known bug status here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1662227?comments=all

Comment: Questions about bugs are off-topic. I'm flagging this question to be closed

Answer (score 3):

According to [bug report #1662227](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1662227) that's because the PPA for LibreOffice doesn't provide translation files for languages aside from English.

You can either

1. safely ignore this warning message as a mostly cosmetic issue or
2. remove/disable the LibreOffice PPA and use the packages from Canonical's repositories instead.

Comment: "2. change to English," does not work, see bug report #1662227 you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than downloading from PPA, you can try installing it using snap.

`sudo snap install libreoffice`

to enable snap packages in 14.04 run

`sudo apt-get install snapd`

Sources:
[libreoffice 5.3 snap package](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/install-libreoffice-5-3-ubuntu-snap),
[snap in ubuntu 14.04](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/install-snap-apps-ubuntu-14-04)

Make sure to purge existing installation first.

Comment: I know that's an option. But I prefer a PPA for now. I have always used it and it has work fine. I just want to know if it's actually a bug with the PPA or there is something wrong with my system.

Comment: @CarlosEstrada, [this user](http://askubuntu.com/questions/879497/apt-spewing-warnings-after-libreoffice-update) is facing the same problem as you. It seems everyone blamed `LO 5.3`

Comment: I made a report in launchpad. By the way, the snap of libreoffice is working great. Thank you.

Comment: @CarlosEstrada, glad to know that. However, the snap LibreOffice have some bug too, you'll face problems with custom themes, also, some files outside snaps sandbox will be unreachable for LibreOffice.

Comment: snap does not install on 14.04 and it has been like that for a long while

Answer (score 0):

The packages description in debian/control in the PPA is wrong and says the l10n-*-packages for 5.3 would include l10n-5.2.

The package has to be rebuilt; see [This Ubuntu Users forum post](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/post/8839147/) for a How-To.