# Cannot install updates Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, updates

I get a message which says "Package Managers cannot be resolved" when I attempt to install regular updates.

When I try to install from the Terminal with sudo apt-get update I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l10n
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package libreoffice-l1
```

I can't seem to install updates anymore. What is the issue? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04: Error with "apt-get update": W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880447/ubuntu-14-04-error-with-apt-get-update-w-ignoring-provides-line-with-depcom)

Comment: Try importing the gpg key with the following command: gpg --recv-key 1397BC53640DB551

Comment: Thanks but this did not work. Same error appears

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no public key available for the following key IDs 1397BC53640DB551](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766883/there-is-no-public-key-available-for-the-following-key-ids-1397bc53640db551)